# Strict CSP: How to set nonce for styled components in next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

So, I'm attempting to populate the style components in my next.js project with a nounce attribute, but without success. The style-src of CSP is being set, but because nounce is not being set in the styles an error is being thrown. What else do I need to do to make this work?

What I have so far is as follows:

server.js

```
server.use((req, res, next) => {
  // nonce should be base64 encoded
  res.locals.styleNonce = Buffer.from(uuidv4()).toString('base64')
  next()
});

  server.use('*', (req, res, next) => {
    global.__webpack_nonce__ = res.locals.styleNonce;
    next()
  });

  server.use(helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
      directives: {
          styleSrc: ["'self'", (req, res) => `'nonce-${res.locals.styleNonce}'`],
      }
  }));
```

_document.js

```
export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  static getInitialProps({ renderPage }) {
    const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet();
    const page = renderPage(App => props => sheet.collectStyles(<App {...props} />));
    const styleTags = sheet.getStyleElement();
    return { ...page, styleTags };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang="en">
        <Head>{this.props.styleTags}</Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you get it to work?

Comment: @TheLearner No, unfortunately.

Comment: Also struggling with this, unsure what to do aside from completely remove my CSP or replace styled components....

Answer (score 0):

In `document.js`, while the nonce has to be provided via props Next.js has the functionality to apply nonce to all loaded scripts/links in `head` and in `body` - given it is provided.

The only major issue I face are conditionally loaded scripts within `next/head` on components' level, for example after accepting cookies... there things get more complicated.

```
  render() {
    const { styleTags, language, nonce } = this.props;

    return (
      <html lang={language}>
        <Head {...{ nonce }}>
          {styleTags}
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript {...{ nonce }} />
        </body>
      </html>
    );
  }
```